# How do I make a Linux C program that supports piping in to it via the shell?

Tags: c, linux, unix

There are certain programs in Linux that can take input from other programs with a syntax like this:

`echo neofetch | pacman -S -`

which will pipe "neofetch" into pacman in place of the single dash, resulting in it installing neofetch. How can I make my own C program for Linux that supports this syntax?

I already know that to take piped input into a program you would use stdin, but i don't know how to do that. I have not found any other info on this topic, only stuff about `pipe()`, which doesn't seem to be the way to do this.

Comment: `I already know that to take piped input into a program you would use stdin, but i don't know how to do that.` You just read stdin. Not sure what you're having trouble with.

Comment: i'm literally having trouble with this specific part. i don't know how to do that.

Comment: scanf, getchar, fgets can all read stdin

Comment: Don't you need to select, poll, or epoll to avoid infinite waiting for terminal input if there's nothing in stdin to read though?

Comment: You wrote "which will pipe "neofetch" into pacman in place of the single dash". No, that is not what that does. The `pacman` command requires a file name. The `-` argument is special-cased by pacman to tell it to read from stdin rather than a named file. Using `-` is just a common convention used by a lot of programs. There is nothing magical about using a hyphen. Reading from stdin in a program written in C is trivial (as others have already told you). Yet you haven't accepted either answer so it is not clear what your real question is.

Comment: pacman does not read files.

Comment: @Tulen662, Sigh. Yes, technically you are correct. But it uses the `-` convention to indicate that it should read a package name from stdin rather than treat the CLI argument as a literal package name. And you still haven't accepted any of the answers that do answer your question. At this point I am wondering if you are competent to write software. P.S., I downvoted your answer because it doesn't actually your question in a way not already answered by others.

Comment: FFS! You added this comment to the most relevant answer: "i don't think this specific question requires any code?" Yes, it does. You should have shown us the code you wrote so we have a better idea what you are trying to do and where you had a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any function that reads from stdin will read from this pipe. That's the point of stdin. For example, this program would read a character at a time from stdin and write it to stdout. With `|`, the `stdout` of `echo` will be attached to the stdin of this program:

```
int main() {
    char c;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        putchar(c);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Anything that can read stdin (fileno 0) works this way. `read`, `scanf`, etc. For example, using `fread` in chunks of 100 bytes from stdin and writing them to stdout:

```
int main() {
    char buffer[100];
    size_t bytesRead;
    while ((bytesRead = fread(buffer, 1, 100, stdin)) > 0) {
        fwrite(buffer, 1, bytesRead, stdout);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

A core design philosophy of Unix is that "everything is a file." So the output of the left side of the pipe is a "file" (a fake file) called stdout, and the right side is the same, called stdin. The "pipe" carries data between the two.

Answer (score 5):

`-` is just a special value to represent `stdin` instead of read from a file. So, it's pretty common to initialise a `FILE*` with either `stdin` or the results of `fopen`, depending on the value of the command-line argument.

Something like:

```c
const char* filename = argv[1];
FILE *file = (0==strcmp(filename, "-") ? stdin : fopen(filename, "r"));
```

Comment: well this is quite unreadable

Comment: i guess you mean that in a program that reads a file, you can specify `-` instead of a file to make it read from stdin. but i'm trying to make my program read an argument from stdin, and it doesn't read files at all.

Comment: @Tulen662 Re. `"i'm trying to make my program read an argument from stdin"`: what program?  You haven't provided any code at all.

Comment: i don't think this specific question requires any code? it's a program that takes arguments, parses them and gives appropriate output, and i want to make it able to read an argument from stdin.

Answer (score -1):

Okay, after sleeping and clearing up my brainfog I realized how much of a stupid question this was. In my specific case I can just use `scanf()`:

```
for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
  if (argv[i][0] == '-') {
    if (argv[i][1] == '\0') {
      if (numexists == false) {
        scanf("%ld", &num);
        numexists = true;
      } else
        exit(1);
...
```

Sorry for wasting everyone's time. I was too tired to write code, or even to write the question properly.

Comment: Hopefully you realize that in the future if you are too tired to write code or formulate a good question you should go to bed and deal with the problem the next day.

Comment: Also, your solution has multiple problems. For example, you shouldn't be using nested `if` conditionals to check whether the argument is a literal `-`. Simply do `if (strcmp(argv[i]), "-") == 0`. You also do not correctly handle stdin data that is not a single integer.